# String AsRef impl vs string slice type?

Tags: rust

New to rust

Trying to wrap my head around AsRef impl:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    println!("trait_and_dispatch");

    let s1 = String::from("string");
    let _ = str_len(&s1); // valid 
    let _ = str_len(s1); // valid 
    
    let s2 = String::from("string");
    let _ = str_len_2(&s2); // valid 
    let _ = str_len_2("string"); // valid 
}


// How is this more useful as compared to str_len_2 ?
fn str_len(s: impl AsRef<str>) -> usize {
    let _s = s.as_ref();
    _s.len()
}

fn str_len_2(s: &str) -> usize {
    s.len()
}
```

The only differnce I see is that in str_len_2, we cannot give in String.

Comment: Well, the first accepts any type implementing `AsRef<str>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is getting into the realm of opinion a bit, but I would argue that `str_len_2` is equally useful and is more honest. The only major players in the standard library that implement [`AsRef<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) are `str`, `String`, and [`Drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.Drain.html). `str` is already the right type, `String` derefs to `str` (as you found out in your third example), and `Drain` is niche (If you're coercing a `Drain` to a `str`, I'd rather you do it explicitly because that's a somewhat odd thing to do). And while, theoretically, someone could come along and write a crate with a novel `AsRef<str>` impl for their type, I can't think of any practical examples of that. So `str_len` is just `str_len_2` with more steps.

The place I most often see `AsRef` come in handy is with the other string-like types such as [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html). `Path` is sort of like `str` except that whereas the latter is a UTF-8 string slice, the former is a slice of characters suitable as a pathname on your target system (on some operating systems, filenames may use other character encodings than UTF-8). If you're writing a function that takes a filename, the most logical argument type is `&T` where `T: AsRef<Path>`. Once you call `as_ref` on it, you get a `Path`, but it can be called uniformly with `&String`, `&str`, `&PathBuf`, `&Path`, `&OsString`, or `&OsStr`. Basically anything vaguely string-like can be used to call your function in that case.

In summary, using `AsRef` to go *to* `&str` would seem a bit odd to me, but using `AsRef` to go *from* `&str` (which has the wonderful property that you can write string literals of that type directly in your code) to some other string-like type (such as `&OsStr` or `&Path`) automatically is very handy.